# How can I make an ajax call using jQuery every second?

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, load

Okay, so I managed to get everything running - one last thing. Basically, one jQuery+ajax function adds 15 seconds to the date and adds a new row to MySQL. I need to put in a new row so I can get the last 5 rows for the history:

```
<?php 
include("inc/dblink.inc");
$itemid = intval($_POST['i']);
$bid = intval($_POST['b']);
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE itemid=$itemid ORDER BY bidid DESC LIMIT 0,1"));
$date = $row['date'];
$newdate = strtotime($date);
$newerdate = ($newdate + 15);
$newestdate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $newerdate);
mysql_query("INSERT INTO test (date,bid,itemid) VALUES ('$newestdate','$bid','$itemid')");
?>
```

The second script refreshes every second and displays the data from the table.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function()
{
$('#timeleft').load('gettime.php', { i: <?=$itemid;?> }).show();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "gettime.php",
    data: ({i : <?=$itemid;?>}),
    success: function(data){
        var s = data;
        var t = s.split(/[- :]/);
        var d = new Date(t[0], t[1]-1, t[2], t[3], t[4], t[5]);
        $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: d,compact: true, 
        description: ''});
    }
});
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Here's gettime.php

```
<?php 
include("inc/dblink.inc");
$itemid = intval($_POST['i']);
$row = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test WHERE itemid='$itemid' ORDER BY bidid DESC LIMIT 0,1"));
$date = $row['date'];
echo $date;
?>
```

And I also used Keith Wood's jQuery countdown script found in http://keith-wood.name/js/jquery.countdown.js

The problem:

This line `$('#timeleft').load('gettime.php', { i: <?=$itemid;?> }).show();` is good. The new time with 15 seconds added shows up without a problem. It's the countdown I'm having issues with. It doesn't add 15 seconds to the timer but if I refresh the whole page, I can see that 15 seconds was added.

What am I doing wrong? Fairly new with jQuery. Thanks!

You can see it in action [here](http://angkas.ph/testarea/index.php).

Comment: There are a little different technologies for this kind of "interactive" applications, Mike. Please contact me, I'll show you some examples.

Comment: @Mushex Send me an e-mail mrbsan(at)gmail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of major issues here, and some minor ones.

### Date Format

It's much simpler to work with a unix timestamp rather than a formatted date. PHP and javascript are very similar in this regard. Both are based on the same "epoch", 00:00 1 Jan 1970. UNIX/PHP work in seconds from that date and javascript works in milliseconds. Therefore a javascript `Date` object can be initialized with `new Date(unix_timestamp * 1000);` without the need for tricky string handling.

### Countdown

Countdown is designed to free-run down to zero with a resolution of 1 second (then fire an optional callback function). With a poll interval of 1 second, it's not necessary to reinitialize the countdown timer every time - only when the returned timestamp has changed.

#### Efficiency

With `setinterval`, it is kinder to client processors to create as many objects/strings as possible once outside the `setinterval` function. This particularly applies to jQuery statements with (static) selectors, as these cause the (potentially large) DOM to be searched.

Putting all that together, my javascript would look like this:

```
$(function(){
    var $$ = {//cached jQuery objects
        timeleft: $('#timeleft'),
        defaultCountdown: $('#defaultCountdown')
    };
    var map_1 = {//namespace for setInterval and countdown data
        url: 'gettime.php',
        lastTimeStamp: 0,
        countdown_settings: {until:null, compact:true, description:''},
        itemid: <?=$itemid;?>
    };
    var auto_refresh = setInterval(function() {
        $$.timeleft.load(map_1.url, {i:map_1.itemid}).show();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: map_1.url,
            data: {i:map_1.itemid},
            success: function(unixTimeStamp) {
                unixTimeStamp = parseInt(unixTimeStamp);
                if(unixTimeStamp !== map_1.lastTimeStamp) {
                    map_1.countdown_settings.until = new Date(parseInt(unixTimeStamp) * 1000);
                    $$.defaultCountdown.countdown(map_1.countdown_settings);
                    map_1.lastTimeStamp = unixTimeStamp;
                }
            }
        });
    }, 1000);
});
```

Of course, to make this work, the PHP statement `echo $date;` will need to be modified to echo the unix timestamp representation of the date. That should be fairly trivial with knowledge of the date format as stored in the db.

*Edit: Unix epoch is 00:00 (midnight) 1 Jan 1970, not 12:00 (midday), doh! Javascript is the same so no negative affect on the code.*

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on java & php dates. I was leaning towards that direction but didn't know that fact. Let me try the things you've included here. I really appreciate the help. Thanks!

Comment: To make things even simpler, you can store your dates in the database as their UNIX epoch representation (in an `INT` field if I remember correctly), and to convert them to human readable form only for display purposes. This approach is commonly adopted.

Answer (score 2):

Your date object i.e. 'd' is initialized only once i.e. the first time the page loads. Find a way to re-initialize it every time you run the countdown function.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I figured. And that's where I got lost.

Comment: Try using Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) to inspect your JavaScript and verify if that is in fact the problem.

Comment: Also, try defining the date variable outside the success callback function. What I mean by that is define it as global variable, not local to the success function. You will obviously update it in the success function though

Answer (score 1):

I think your php script variable in this line is generate only once, that is why, it works only once (that is every page refresh).

```
 $('#timeleft').load('gettime.php', { i: <?=$itemid;?> }).show();
```

update your JS success code to update the variable, so the page is updated for every call.

Comment: If I add another line, let's say `$('#prevbids').load('prevbids.php', { i: <?=$itemid;?> }).show();` - it gets executed. It's just the ajax call that's giving me problems.

Answer (score 1):

Add this in ajax:

```
$('#defaultCountdown').countdown('option', {
    format: 'DHMS', until : d
});
```

Works for me.